# XlsxWriter formula output with @

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a script that creates a DF. I export DF to Excel , and write cells as follows :

```
for i in range(2, len(CODIGO_AGRUPADOR['marca'])+2):
                
        worksheet.write_formula('G'+str(i),f'=SI(F{i} ="","FALTA CONTROLAR","REVISADO")')
```

the problem is that in the .xlsx cells I get :

```
=@SI(F2 ="";"FALTA CONTROLAR";"REVISADO")
```

And it doesn´t work beacuase of the @ ----what am I doing Wrong?. I´m doing the same as documentation indicates  in https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=write%20formula#write_formula

but I can´t find a way to get the correct format without @

Does anybody know what could be wrong? . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two things. First the function/formula must be in English. Second, the @ indicates that the formula should by an array formula or a dynamic array formula. Both of these are explained in: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html